# Visualizing repetitive tasks in Gantt Chart in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, bar-chart, visualization

I'm trying to make a chart (either with lines or bars) to show periods of time in certain Stages. Using the data below, the closest I've gotten is to try to get a Gantt chart and turn off the color for the start date, only showing the duration. Rather than the duration in days on the x-axis, I'd like it just to be dates (months or years).

(screenshot - Gantt chart example - note the multiple appearances of "Cultivate")

[image]

It's close to what I want, but the stage can be reentered multiple times. So I would like those separate Cultivate periods/bars on one line. Something like this:

[image: hand drawing of what I'd like this to look like; sorry a bit blurry]

Data:

| STAGE | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cultivate | 4/25/2008 | 3/29/2012 |
| Qualify | 3/30/2012 | 7/18/2012 |
| Cultivate | 7/19/2012 | 2/22/2015 |
| Open | 2/23/2015 | 4/17/2020 |
| Cultivate | 4/18/2020 | 6/24/2020 |
| Steward | 6/25/2020 | 3/31/2022 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do it by the default chart creator.

A workaround would be building your Spreadsheet with the Gantt Chart in cells and apply conditional formatting for repeating tasks.

You can check it on this spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VOxoDlL5auzigm1FSt2gmbjSSmkoRMhVlQiLsKwN4Kk/edit#gid=1539711303

The idea comes from https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/split-a-task-in-gantt-chart-in-google-sheets/

I tested it out and it works well, but I think that it only accepts one repetitive task